# jQuery UI Draggable Drags every Element within outer element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have some basic HTML like this

```
<ul>
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  <li>Item3</li>
<ul>
```

I want to make the li tags draggable but in a different way then usual.

When someone drags any of the `li` tags I want it to also drag the li tags surrounding it on the same x axis.

NOTE: I can't drag the entire `ul` tag, I need to drag the individual `li` tags and all surrounding `li` tags within the `ul` tag.

Comment: That largely depends upon how you're defining your *x axis*.

Comment: could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving each individual element proved to be way to much of a performance hit, so the way I solved it was by first wrapping a div around all of the elements:

```
$('li').wrapAll('<div class="draggableDiv"></div>');
```

If you're ul tag is set to overflow hidden and you need to keep that behavior (for a slider type application), this is the best way i've found to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think my sample may solve your problem.Please check below link:

```
 $("#dragAbleElement").draggable({
    revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
    containment: $(".container"), // stick to demo-frame if present
    cursor: "move",
    start: function () {
        //code lines
    },
    stop: function(){
        //code lines
    }
});
```

[Sample Code](http://jsfiddle.net/eshugoel24/73bjwpuc/)

Please let me know if you will face any issue.

Comment: This makes no difference it still only drags the individual dragable element, it needs to drag every draggable element inside of an outer element.

Comment: Please check updated code. That was my bad misunderstood the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/eshugoel24/73bjwpuc/1/

Comment: @Jordash maybe you get your solution.